# How to import SSL certificate to system?

Tags: ssl, installation, ssl-certificate

how can i add my self signed SSL certificate to thrusted in system? i mean programmaticaly,during the installation process of my program.  How should i do that?

Comment: What OS/platform, in what language etc.?

Comment: visual c++, windows..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trusted for what - the current user's web browser? It's probably cheaper to pay the $20 or so it costs for a low-assurance certificate with good browser recognition.

Comment: +1, exactly. And even if you wanted to do it the hard way the procedure is different and unique for each environment: IE, Java, Firefox, Opera, ...